# PHP: Unlink a little too effective

Tags: php, svg, unlink

I'm in the process of developing a PHP webpage that constructs a .SVG file from a SQL database on the fly, embeds it in the page, and enables a user to interact with it.  These temporary files take on the form SVG[RandomNumber].svg and the unlink function successfully deletes the files with no error messages.

Here's the problem: I assumed that if I invoked the *unlink* function after the SVG file had loaded for the user, the webpage would be unaffected since the user's browser would have cached the file or whatnot.  Everything works perfectly when no unlink command is present in the code; however, 'unlinking' anywhere -- even at the end of the webpage, causes no object to show at all.  In Firefox there's no trace of the object, and in IE I receive the error "The webpage cannot be found."

So have I deleted the file before the browser uploads it? What's the best way to deal with the general situation?

Thank you.

Comment: Are you actually unlinking after the *image* loads, or after the *page* (that contains the image) loads?  Both can't really happen at the same time...the browser needs to get and parse the page before it can even know to load the image.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I'm a bit new to development and haven't caught on to the order in which various entities are loaded. I suppose I've been invoking the command even before the page finishes loading.  Is there a better place to invoke the commands, or another consistent way of removing these temporary files automatically?

Comment: I personally might think about serving the file via a PHP script rather than just as a link to a static file.  The script would of course know the file was downloaded, and could delete it safely.  Though at that point, depending on the nature of the image, it might almost be better to leave the file there for a while.

Comment: It would be better to defer deletion of temporary files with a cron job, that would delete files older then its period.

Comment: [Also posted to Answer 1 below:] What I'd been doing prior to this is using **echo** to 'print' out a faux-SVG entity right into the webpage. Doing so yielded a functioning page but created HTML validation errors, so I thought it would be better to create a file on the fly, embed it, and then delete it.  That said, if I could **echo** out an object that without getting those errors, I'd be very happy.

Comment: Doesn't HTML 5 let you stick SVGs right into the page?  I seem to remember something about it recognizing the SVG namespace.

Comment: Aha! For eternity I've just had XHTML 1.0 Transitional lying around at the top of my webpage. I'll see if converting it to HTML 5 straightens things up.

Comment: Wow, that made things simple. That's the solution -- skip the creation of the freestanding file altogether and just roll it into HTML5! Thank you. This also provided the impetus to make sure my HTML is in tip-top shape.

Answer (score 0):

It might be useful to change workflow and don't create temporaries. When image is used only once or it's generation is not a big deal you can try to generate it on-the-fly in following fashion

```
<?php
// We'll be outputting a SVG
header('Content-type: Content-Type: image/svg+xml');

// It will be called image.svg
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="image.svg"');

// Don't cache
header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate");
header("Expires: " . date("D, j M Y H:i:s")); 

// The PDF source is in original.pdf
generate_svg_from_db('image.svg');
?>
```

Comment: I'll have to look into that approach. (I've never dealt with the header() command before.) What I'd been doing prior to this is using *echo* to 'print' out a faux-SVG entity right into the webpage. Doing so yielded a functioning page but created HTML validation errors, so I thought it would be better to create a file on the fly, embed it, and then delete it.  I like the alternative workflow idea, however.